# Convert SQLite query to Realm query Android

Tags: android, sqlite, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Having this method that return a list of Objects filtered by query

```
public List<table_People> getPeople(String filter)
{
    List<table_People> items = new ArrayList<>();

    filter = filter.trim();
    filter = filter.toUpperCase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM People " +
            "WHERE (UPPER(LastName || FirstName) LIKE '%" + filter + "%') " +
            "OR (UPPER(FirstName || LastName) LIKE '%" + filter + "%') ";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            table_People item = new table_People(
                    cursor.getInt((cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"))),
                    cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("FirstName"))),
                    cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("LastName")))
            );
            items.add(item);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return items;
}
```

How can I convert this in Realm query?

Most of all, I have issues about the WHERE CLAUSE.

I need this WHERE CLAUSE because i need to search by FirstName + LastName or LastName + FirstName.

For example
`John Smith`
`Smith John` return always a record.

Answer (score 0):

```
    realm.where(People.class)
            .beginGroup()
            .equalTo("FirstName", "John").equalTo("LastName", "Smith")
            .endGroup()
            .or()
            .beginGroup()
            .equalTo("LastName", "John").equalTo("FirstName", "Smith")
            .endGroup()
            .findAll();
```